# Can AFNetworking do request like curl -v?

Tags: ios, iphone, curl, afnetworking

I want to make a http-test-tool to help us find users problem using our apps, and I like making tests using `curl -v`.
Every line is useful in debugging. Such as the IP, Port, Cert, and Headers, and so on.
Is there any tools on iOS platform can do this?

```
curl -v https://stackoverflow.com/
*   Trying 151.101.129.69...
* Connected to stackoverflow.com (151.101.129.69) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.stackexchange.com
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: stackoverflow.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Expires: Mon, 07 Nov 2016 12:33:31 GMT
< Last-Modified: Mon, 07 Nov 2016 12:32:31 GMT
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Request-Guid: 61dedc6f-13f6-4ea6-970a-a596f885e29c
< Content-Length: 250615
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Date: Mon, 07 Nov 2016 12:32:31 GMT
< Via: 1.1 varnish
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Served-By: cache-hkg6825-HKG
< X-Cache: MISS
< X-Cache-Hits: 0
< X-Timer: S1478521950.280986,VS0,VE949
< Vary: *
< X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
< Set-Cookie: prov=ca5856bc-b473-5203-b21e-2b2eb6516fee; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
<
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Anyway it's not as immediate as adding a flag to the command line like your example with `curl -v`.

Let's take the `GET:parameters:success:failure:` [method](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.1.0/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html#//api/name/GET:parameters:success:failure:) on the `AFHTTPSessionManager` for performing a GET request. The declaration for the method is:

```
- (nullable NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                            parameters:(nullable id)parameters 
                               success:(nullable void (^) (NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id _Nullable responseObject))success
                               failure:(nullable void (^) (NSURLSessionDataTask *_Nullable task, NSError *error))failure;
```

There are two blocks of interest here: The first is included in case of a successful response (named very smartly `success`) and the other for a `failure` in the request.

Both of the blocks return a parameter of type NSURLSessionDataTask (which is nullable on the failure event, if that's the case then there was no response, most likely to happen when there's no internet connection). According to the [Apple Documentation for `NSURLSessionDataTask`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiondatatask#relationships), which inherits from [`NSURLSessionTask`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiontask?language=objc), it is possible to get the response object and then the headers. Here a simple [example taken from Github](https://gist.github.com/Air-Craft/67b25faa9d6470daa079):

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)[task response]);
NSDictionary *headers = [response allHeaderFields];
// Do something with the headers in the response here...
```

Further from here, take a look on the [Symbols for NSURLSessionTask](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiontask?language=objc#symbols) and take what you need.